# C# dropdown under textbox like combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have tried many way to get the list under the text box but when I move the cursor in the text box and I am going to press f1 so after that i have to get the list below the text box .
Example :  when the billing is done while entering customer name the text box should show drop down list of previous entries.

```cs
private void text1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArguments e)
{
   if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.G)
   {
       Form searchForm = new Form();
       searchForm.Show();
   }
   if (e.KeyChar == 13)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Enter key pressed");
   }
}
```

I am using C# in visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `MySearchForm` appear just under the control (`TextBox` in your case):

```
private void TextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
  if (e.KeyChar == 'G') {
    e.Handled = true;

    // We compute global coordinates that corresponds local ones {0, TextBox1.Height} 
    Point at = (sender as Control).PointToScreen(new Point(0, (sender as Control).Height));

    MySearchForm form = new MySearchForm() {
      StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual,
      Location = at,
    };

    // or form.ShowDialog();
    form.Show();
    ...
 }

  ...
}
```

You may want to elaborate form creation: let's have a look if we have an opened instance, and if we do, move it:

```
MySearchForm form = Application
  .OpenForms
  .OfType<MySearchForm>()
  .LastOrDefault(); 

if (null == form) {
  form = new MySearchForm() {
    StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual,
    Location = at,
  };

  form.Show();
}
else {
  form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
  form.BringToFront();
  form.Location = at;

  if (form.CanFocus)
    form.Focus();   
}
```